# Para que serve o Microsoft Access?

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

É uma pergunta idiota, eu sei.

Quase não tive contato com MS Access. Sei que é um banco de dados. Ele tem alguma coisa de especial? Alguma *feature* digna de nota? Como ele funciona? QuaIs demandas ele atende?

Comment: Assim como toda ferramenta pode se tornar legado, eu creio que o MSAccess já é! Ele só deve "existir" ainda porque sistemas mais antigos talvez o usem, talvez ele tenha funcionalidades especificas, mas nem creio que este seja o motivo dele ainda ser usado eventualmente.

Comment: Ou seja, não perdi nada :D kthxbai

Comment: Não é uma pergunta idiota, embora possa ser negativada porque as respostas vão ser basicamente opinativas, como a minha o foi...

Comment: @epx eu acho interessante perguntas sobre coisas antigas, pq agrega conhecimento.

Comment: É tipo o "MS Paint", mas pra banco de dados.

Comment: Kkkkk x 3 (15 caracteres de comprimento mínimo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MS-Access é mais ou menos equivalente ao Excel e ao Word, mas para banco de dados.

Ele tem um formato próprio de banco (MDB) onde dados, telas, relatórios, programas, etc. ficam juntos. Mas ele também pode ser cliente de qualquer servidor de banco de dados via ODBC. Ou pode-se separar o banco num MDB e a aplicação noutro MDB.

Foi uma plataforma popular, que prometia muito, nos anos 90 para desenvolvimento de sistemas inteiros, pois é programável usando Visual Basic (que também é um fator de popularidade do Excel). Havia um pouco aquela ilusão na época que pequenos negócios poderiam desenvolver seus próprios sistemas sem o auxílio de um desenvolvedor profissional.

É uma ferramenta poderosa porém o Excel prevaleceu como ferramenta de administração de pequenos negócios, visto que também é scriptável e também pode ler bancos de dados, há inclusive um forte mercado secundário de planilhas e plugins Excel. O Excel também tem uma interface intuitiva (planilha eletrônica todo mundo conhece, bancos de dados nem tanto) e a curva de aprendizado é mais linear - em Access é fácil fazer coisas básicas, mas na hora que precisa de algo um pouquinho mais complexo, a coisa engrossa bem rápido.

Fora isso, a complexidade dos sistemas aumentou muito desde então - nos anos 90 um pequeno negócio tinha um computador, no máximo um punhado ligado via rede local, hoje em dia quando se fala "sistema" já se pressupõe acesso via Web, acesso remoto, alta disponibilidade, etc. etc. por menor que seja o negócio, então aquela ilusão de "faça-você-mesmo" ou de contratar o sobrinho para fazer sistema no fim-de-semana já não existe.

Comment: Deu um feeling já do que era o MS Access... +1 e provavelmente vou aceitar. Só acho que faltou incluir um segundo parágrafo detalhando melhor a primeira frase da resposta.

Comment: vou aceitar mas não deixe de notar meu comentário logo acima. E obrigado pela resposta :)

Comment: Fiz o que pediu, se quiser que eu expanda mais para outra direção, peço avisar.